# AttributeError: module 'networkx.algorithms' has no attribute 'smallworld' when I try to use NetworkX's Small-World module

Tags: python, networkx

I was trying to use NetworkX's `sigma` function to get the small-world coefficient of a graph. The documentation states [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.smallworld.sigma.html#networkx.algorithms.smallworld.sigma) that that can be found in: `networkx.algorithms.smallworld.sigma`

However, if I try to perform the following call:

```
nx.algorithms.smallworld.sigma(G)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'networkx.algorithms' has no attribute 'smallworld'
```

Also, Spyder's Intellisense does not seem to be aware of that package. (I'm using Python 3.6.5, NetworkX 2.5.1, and Spyder 3.2.8; for the record, yes, I do know that that's an old version of Spyder).

I'm slightly confused because I'm able to do calls like:

```
nx.algorithms.community.girvan_newman(G)
nx.algorithms.cluster.average_clustering(G)
```

In those cases, the modules are exactly where the documentation says they'll be.

I am aware that the cource code for this can be found [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/smallworld.html). However, I would prefer not to have to manually add this to my project.

Can anyone point out my mistake (or suggest a workaround so that I don't have to add the code to my project manually)?

Comment: Which version of `networkx` is installed?

Comment: @MichaelRuth 2.5.1

Comment: Can't reproduce. :/ Have you tried to the good old uninstall / reinstall networkx?

Comment: @Frodnar Not yet, I'll try that